# is it possible to bind the back button jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) to make a basic html5 app. I am doing something where when you click a button, it adds new class to the body [like this jsfiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/RwHWC/1/).

The issue with this however is that when the user clicks 'back' they are still left with the newly added class.

So the question / challenge is how does one remove the most recently added class if the back button is clicked? In other words, how can I make the back button trigger a function?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to bind a function to the BACK button.
I couldnt find a straight forward way for it. One of the hacks is to  put a click event for all anchor tags and on click check if the grandchild span of the anchor tag has the innertext as "Done" or anything which u specify as 
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Done";

Then u can remove the class there. However this is not a good way.
Do tell me if you find a cleaner solution.

Comment: cheers for that - if I find something I'll post another comment and let you know.